# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in node js during updating data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js developement and encountered an error.
First of all here the code inside `controller.js`.

```
exports.updateCar = async (req, res,next) => {
    const {name} = req.fields

    try {

        await updateCarService(name,next, (data) =>{

        if(data == null || data){
            res.status(201).json({
                status:true,
                message:'updated',
                data
            });

            return
        }
       })

       next()
   } catch(e) {

     res.sendStatus(500) && next(e)
   }   
  };
```

and here the method inside `services.js`.

```
function updateCars(existingCar,callback){
  Car.find({name : existingCar.name}, function (err, docs) {
      if (docs.length){
        //callback('Car exists already',null);
        callback(err,docs)
      }else{
          existingCar.save(function(err,carr){
            console.log('-------',carr)
            callback(err,carr);
          });
      }
  });


}


const updateCarService = async (name,next,callback) => {
try{
  return await Car.find({name : name},(err,existingCar) => {
    if (!err && existingCar.length > 0){

        existingCar[0].name = 'audi';

        updateCars(existingCar[0],(err2,car) =>{


            if (err2 || !car){
                console.log('error updated car: ',err2);
            }else{
                console.log('car updated: ',car);
                return callback(car)
            }

            return

        });
    } 
    else  if (!err && existingCar.length == 0){

     return callback(null)

    }
 })


}
catch(e){
  console.log(error)
}

}
```

After updating data i get error that :

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I have tried many possible ways to solve this issue but i couldn't got any solution.
Please help me to resolve this issue.Also if any of style of coding is not good then correct me.

Comment: This error usually occurs when you are unwillingly sending response again to the client. You should post whole stack trace to figure out  from where error originated.

Comment: Last line where error occured in stacktrace is return callback(car)

Comment: How are you calling this route? and why are you calling `next` there? remove the `next()` because you are not using any promises inside your code just some random async awaits. The code has multiple basic code problems, but for now most probably removing the `next` would solve the issue. But please go through some js best practices or github code for popular repositories. The current code is very very messy

Comment: Can u please suggest me how can i improve my current code